# Can I get my Connected App Listed in App Exchange?

Tags: appexchange, connected-apps

I want to integrate my Web App ( running on `*.mydomain.com` ) using connected App ( APIs ) of Salesforce.com. Which means, Salesforce.com users can access my Web App seamlessly.

Can I now List this Connected App  to appexchange.salesforce.com ? Or is it that Connected Apps are available for Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can list connected apps on the AppExchange. You will need to add the connected app to a managed package. See the [Connected Apps section in the ISVforce guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/connected_app_overview.htm) for more info.